# Dismiss two modal interface controllers at the same time in watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, watchkit, modalviewcontroller

There are three `Interface Controllers`:  IC1->IC2->IC3. IC2 and IC3 are presented modally. 
I want to dismiss IC3 and present IC1. So I want to go back to my main `Interface Controller` ( IC1 ) from the trird `Interface Controller`. 
But the problem is  - I cannot skip animation of dismissing IC2.

I tried to do this:

IC1.h:

`@interface IC1 : WKInterfaceController <ModalICDelegate>`

IC1.m:

```
-(void)dismissSecondAndShowThird
{
    [self presentControllerWithName:@"IC3" context:nil];
}
```

IC2.h:

```
@protocol ModalICDelegate

-(void)dismissSecondAndShowThird;

@end;

@interface IC2 : WKInterfaceController 

@property (nonatomic) id<ModalICDelegate> delegate;
```

IC2.m:

```
    - (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
    {
//CONTEXT HERE IS PREVIOUS INTERFACE CONTROLLER
        self.delegate=(IC1*)context;
    }
```

So when i need to show IC3 i do this in IC2.m:

```
[self dismissController];
[self.delegate dismissSecondAndShowThird];
```

But I want to display IC3 without any animation of dismissing IC2.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: No, I changed the logic. It was not possible to do what i wanted on watchos 1.0